# Node management tool

Tags: ros, nodes, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone know about a node management GUI. Something that allows
you to get an overview of the running nodes, manage starting and stopping
nodes. See if any node has crashed etc. I guess you could think of it
as a GUI on top of roslaunch or something.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9995/node-management-tool/) by [Hordur](https://answers.ros.org/users/418/hordur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 544 on 2011-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This doesn't exist.  You're not the first to think of it and some informal design has been done, but there is nothing usable.

---

Originally posted by [Straszheim](https://answers.ros.org/users/44/straszheim/) with karma: 426 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0